# DataFrame cannot be sliced direfctly using [] operator as Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

This is something I just realized, hope it's useful to pandas beginners like me - Why does the last line gives an error? Because when selecting one single column out of one DataFrame, it becomes a Series, which can be directly indexed with concise syntax as []. However, when you are selecting a list of column(s) from a DataFrame, it still returns a DataFrame which cannot be sliced directly using [].

```
In[178]: df
Out[177]: 
    name  age sex        job
0   John   15   M    Student
1   Mike   30   M      Labor
2   Lily   41   F    Student
3   Dave   66   M      Labor
4    Sam   23   F  Scientist
5   Luke    7   M      Labor
6  Ellen   80   F      Labor
7  Jacob   52   M      Actor
In[179]: df.set_index('name', inplace=True, drop=True)
In[180]: df
Out[179]: 
       age sex        job
name                     
John    15   M    Student
Mike    30   M      Labor
Lily    41   F    Student
Dave    66   M      Labor
Sam     23   F  Scientist
Luke     7   M      Labor
Ellen   80   F      Labor
Jacob   52   M      Actor
In[181]: df['age']['John']
Out[180]: 15
In[182]: type(df['age'])
Out[181]: pandas.core.series.Series
In[183]: type(df[['age']])
Out[182]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
In[184]: df[['age']]['John'] # This is Wrong
```

Comment: I am precisely trying to make it easier to read. But I couldn't find how to paste the whole background and foreground coloring from the IDE(PyCharm in this case) to StackOverflow as many python programmers are used to - it worked perfectly in an Outlook email. Please teach me. I read the HELP, I only find basic HTML support. I couldn't find language specific highlight support, sorry.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm going to edit all my posts. Trust me, I had the best intention in mind when I decided to post pictures. It's actually much harder to do screenshot, save the pic and then upload there, than just Ctrl+K on the code text.

Answer (score 1):

For the last line to work you need to have it this way `df[['age']]['age'][df['name'] =='John']`. This is obviously bad style. The reason your last line of code is not working is that `df[['age']]` returns a Data Frame with a single column named *'age'* and index from 0 to 7.

```
In [4]: df[['age']]
Out[4]:
   age
0   15
1   30
2   41
3   66
4   23
5    7
6   80
7   52
```

When you try to slice the data frame using *'John'*, Pandas checks the data frame and is not able to find any column named *John*. You can do the following to find the age of John

```
In [15]: df[['age']]['age'][df['name'] =='John']
Out[15]:
0    15
Name: age, dtype: int64

# get the exact value
In [16]: df[['age']]['age'][df['name'] =='John'][0]
Out[16]:
15

# or simply
In [18]: df[df['name'] =='John']['age'][0]
Out[18]: 15
```